# Redirecting a domain in a Silverstripe site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe-4

I need to do a domain redirect in my .htaccess file, excluding one url, and what I've got works on the top level

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rhapsody-ide
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rhapsody.health [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rhapsody.health [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://lyniate.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but when it comes to redirecting other pages it sticks a 'index.php' in there, i.e. https://rhapsody.health/corepoint/benefits goes to https://www.lyniate.com/index.php/benefits/

I assume this is caused by the standard SilverStripe redirect:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Which comes afterward.

How do I do both operations at the same time?

Comment: could you please remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$` and test.

Comment: That causes the main site to have an index.php in the URL

Comment: `{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` this condition will redirect all requests to index.php. Do you want to such rule?

Comment: Yes, that is the fundamental rule that makes all Silverstripe pages work. It's the first lot of rules that isn't working properly. Basically I want all rhapsody.health pages to redirect to lyniate.com, except /rhapsody-ide. That needs to be on the rhapsody.health domain